# Book reference for studying Dirichlet Convolution

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation, arithmetic-functions, dirichlet-convolution

Now I am studying elementary number theory, I am interested in arithmetic function, I have studied Burton's Number Theory but I can't find Dirichlet Convolution as a particular topic, I will be highly glad if anyone suggest some good book to study arithmetic function where I can find Dirichlet Convolution in details with some theorem like 'the set of all arithmetic function forms integral domain under pointwise addition and Dirichlet Convolution'. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can look for it in Introduction to Analytic Number Theory by Tom Apostol[Chapter 2], and Introduction to Analytic and Probabilistic Number Theory by Gerald Tenenbaum [Chapter I.2 in 3rd Edition].
These both give a good insight to the topic.

Comment: I have already read Apostol it is well but it requires more theorem related to this topic. Well another isn't studied yet.

Answer (score 0):

Dirichlet convolution is already defined at the beginning of *[Introduction to Arithmetical Functions](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1988-18-02/S0273-0979-1988-15660-1/S0273-0979-1988-15660-1.pdf)* by Paul J. McCarthy.  This book presents a lot of different arithmetical functions providing a nice introduction to the subject. The chapter 4 *Generalizations of Dirichlet Convolution* considers $K$-convolutions: $f\star_K g$, defined as
\begin{align*}
\left(f\star_K g\right)(n)=\sum_{d|n}K(n,d)f(d)g(n/d)\qquad\qquad \text{for all}\  n
\end{align*}
which might also be of interest.